# JavaFX Two steps Registration Form

Tags: database, javafx, controller, registration

I’m going to build two steps registration form using JavaFX. Anyone has an idea how can pass the first controller inputs to the second one. And how can I use those values on action events to update my database?

Here is how I connect my first scene to the second one. And send my inputs to the second scene controller.

```
public void btnNextPage(){

    try{
        Parent fxml = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("stdReg2.fxml"));
        FXMLLoader loader=new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("stdReg2"));
        //Parent root = (Parent) loader.load();

        StdReg2 stdreg2=loader.getController();
        stdreg2.getTexts(txtFirstName.getText(),txtStdid.getText(),txtLastName.getText(),txtBd.getEditor().getText(),txtUsrEmail.getText(),txtUsrPass.getText(),img);
        //Parent fxml = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("stdReg2.fxml"));
        contentArea.getChildren().removeAll();
        contentArea.getChildren().setAll(fxml);

        //StdReg2 stdreg2=fxml.getConroller();

    } catch (IOException ex){
        Logger.getLogger(Dashboard.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        System.out.println(ex);
    }
```

Here how I get first controller inputs to the second controller.

```
public void getTexts(String txtFirstName,String txtStdid, String txtLastName, String txtBd, String txtUsrEmail, String txtUsrPass, File img) throws FileNotFoundException {


    String firstname = txtFirstName;
    String lastname = txtLastName;
    String emid = txtStdid;
    String usrBD = txtBd;
    String usrEmail = txtUsrEmail;
    String usrPass = txtUsrPass;

}
```

My issue is, How can I use this input on my action event and add first controller data and second controller data to my database because I can't use those attributes in another method on the second controller.

Thank you, have a nice day.

Answer (score 1):

In order to get a reference to the controller, you need to create an `FXMLLoader` instance with the correct path, then *use that instance* to load the FXML:

```
public void btnNextPage(){

    try{
        //Parent fxml = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("stdReg2.fxml"));
        //FXMLLoader loader=new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("stdReg2"));
        //Parent root = (Parent) loader.load();

        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("stdReg2.fxml"));
        Parent fxml = loader.load();

        StdReg2 stdreg2 = loader.getController();
        stdreg2.getTexts(txtFirstName.getText(),txtStdid.getText(),txtLastName.getText(),txtBd.getEditor().getText(),txtUsrEmail.getText(),txtUsrPass.getText(),img);
        
        contentArea.getChildren().removeAll();
        contentArea.getChildren().setAll(fxml);


    } catch (IOException ex){
        Logger.getLogger(Dashboard.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        System.out.println(ex);
    }
}
```

It's not clear what the various methods you are calling actually do, but this sets up the correct way to call methods in one controller from another.